# SQL Server - Select Rows, Remove Duplicates But Keep row with highest date

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Considering the following database table in SQL Server 2008:

```
ActionID (PK)    ActionType    ActionDate              UserID  ContentID
1                'Create'      '2013-05-26 18:40:00'   1       10
2                'Create'      '2013-05-26 18:30:00'   2       10
3                'Edit'        '2013-05-26 12:30:00'   5       12
4                'Edit'        '2013-05-26 12:25:00'   5       12
5                'Delete'      '2013-05-26 12:22:00'   6       12
```

I want to write a SQL query that groups by `ContentID` and `ActionType` but where the row with the latest `ActionDate` is returned and other rows ignored, even if they have different `UserID` or other column values.

So what it should return is:

```
ActionID (PK)    ActionType    ActionDate              UserID  ContentID
1                'Create'      '2013-05-26 18:40:00'   1       10
3                'Edit'        '2013-05-26 12:30:00'   5       12
5                'Delete'      '2013-05-26 12:22:00'   6       12
```

But I can't quite figure out how to write the query to do it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One approach would be to use a CTE (Common Table Expression).

With this CTE, you can partition your data by some criteria - i.e. your `ContentID` and `Actiontype` - and have SQL Server number all your rows starting at 1 for each of those "partitions", ordered by the `ActionDate`.

So try something like this:

```
;WITH Actions AS
(
   SELECT 
       ActionID, ActionType, ActionDate, UserID, ContentID,
       RowNum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ContentID, ActionType ORDER BY ActionDate DESC)
   FROM 
       dbo.YourTable
   WHERE
      ......
)
SELECT 
   ActionID, ActionType, ActionDate, UserID, ContentID,
FROM 
   Actions
WHERE
   RowNum = 1
ORDER BY 
   ActionDate DESC
```

Does that approach what you're looking for??

Comment: It won't let me stick on ORDER BY in the WITH Actions bit, but I can put it in the latter SELECT statement. I need to order by the ActionDate column, so would this be an efficient way of doing it?

Comment: @SundayIronfoot: just add the `ORDER BY` to the "outer" `SELECT` that selects the rows from the CTE (as shown in my updated response) - is that what you need?

Answer (score 4):

```
select t1.*
from Table1 t1
inner join (select ContentID, ActionType, max(ActionDate) as MaxDate
            from Table1
            group by ContentID, ActionType) t2
        on t1.ContentID = t2.ContentID
       and t1.ActionType = t2.ActionType
       and t1.ActionDate = t2.MaxDate;
```

Any query that answers your question is liable to produce unexpected results if you have duplicate rows for a {ContentID, ActionType} pair.